# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of date

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to insert some Java object data to *MySQL* with *Spark* SQL. Below is my simplified code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Model implements Serializable {

    private String state;
    private String title;
    private String exportCntry;
    private String filepath;
    private String unit;
    private String frequency; 
    private String Seasonal_adjust; 
    private Date Last_updated;

    private static StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {

              DataTypes.createStructField("state", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("title", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("exportCntry", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("filepath", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("unit", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("frequency", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("Seasonal_adjust", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("Last_updated", DataTypes.DateType, false)
    });

    public static StructType getStructType() {
        return structType;
    }

    public static void setStructType(StructType structType) {
        Model.structType = structType;
    }

    public Object[] getAllValues() {
        return new Object[] { state, title, exportCntry, filepath, unit, frequency, unit, 
                                                        frequency, Seasonal_adjust, Last_updated
        };
    }
}
```

And the following code is the *Spark* SQL code that inserts the above `Model` java objects to *MySQL*.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Queue;

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

public class Processor {

    private static List<String> testData = Arrays.asList(
            "Alabama,ValueofExports,Israel,A/L/I/ALISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26",
            "Alaska,ValueofExports,Israel,A/K/AKISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26",
            "Arizona,ValueofExports,Israel,A/Z/I/AZISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26",
            "Arkansas,ValueofExports,Israel,A/R/I/ARISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26",
            "California,ValueofExports,Israel,C/A/I/CAISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26",
            "Colorado,ValueofExports,Israel,C/O/I/COISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26",
            "Connecticut,ValueofExports,Israel,C/T/I/CTISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26",
            "Delaware,ValueofExports,Israel,D/E/I/DEISRA052SCEN.csv,$,A,NSA,2018-06-26"
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Properties jdbcProps = new Properties();
        jdbcProps.put("user", "root");
        jdbcProps.put("password", "password");

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark Kafka Test").getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate());
      JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(jsc, Durations.milliseconds(1000));    

      JavaRDD<String> rddTest = jsc.parallelize(testData);
      Queue<JavaRDD<String>> queue = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>();
      queue.add(rddTest);
      JavaDStream<String> jds = jssc.queueStream( queue );

        JavaDStream<Model> jdm = jds.map(str -> {
            String[] parameters = new String[str.split(",").length];
            parameters = str.split(",");

            Date date = Date.valueOf(parameters[7]);

            Model data = new Model(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], 
                    parameters[4], parameters[5], parameters[6], date);

            return data;
        });

        jdm.map(e -> {
            Row row = RowFactory.create(e.getAllValues());
            return row;
        }).foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, Model.getStructType());
            df.printSchema();
            df.write()
                    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul",
                            "test", jdbcProps);
        });

        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
        jssc.close();
    }

}
```

But the error is thrown from the *Spark* SQL `insert` statement.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of date
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.StaticInvoke_7$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:289)
```

It seems that the exception is related to `java.sql.Date` object API. The *Spark* SQL `Dataframe.write` method does not work. Did I miss some process?

Comment: **As per the edits on your past questions**, note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @Abra: thanks for wanting to edit here. However, italicising software names does not make them clearer, and can be distracting to readers. Please just ensure they are cased correctly.